Do Ubuntu updates update dependent executables on shared library minor change?
One of the oft-cited benefits of shared libraries is that if we make a minor change in a library which does not change its ABI (e.g. fix implementation bug) we do not need to recompile dependent executable files (they would work with updated library without any changes). Do Ubuntu system updates make use of this fact? I.e. whenever there is a security bugfix in package which provides libXYZ.so, will Ubuntu just install updated libXYZ.so and keep all dependent packages unchanged?
EDIT: links to official docs are highly appreciated as I need a prooflink for my presentation on shared libraries.

Generally, yes, that's how it works. There may be corner cases and exceptions.

@user535733 thanks! Do you have some link which could confirm that Ubuntu updater behaves like this? Background: I'm preparing a presentation about shared libraries and failed to find a prooflink of this behavior.

If the interfaces stay stable, there is no need to update other packages, therefor debian, and ubuntu as well, just add an "-1", or "-2" etc. to the version number.
See https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#list-of-fields
5.6.12 explains how the version numbering works:
[epoch:]upstream_version[-debian_revision]
if you check how the "depends" field works, you'll see there is no need to update other packages unneeded, therefor they will not be rebuild

I think we all agree that there is no need to update them. The question here is whether Ubuntu/Debian in fact do not :)

@yugr: i added a link to the policy, hope that makes it more clear for you
